# How to connect Java 8 with MS Access?

Tags: java, ms-access, java-8, jdbc-odbc

> I am facing some issue to making a login page in java using ms access database.
>   its not getting username and password from ms access database.

```
try
{
String user=t.getText().trim();
String pass=t1.getText().trim();
Class.forName("sun.jdbc.odbc.JdbcOdbcDriver");
Connection con1=DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:odbc:balogin");
Statement stat;
stat=con1.createStatement();
ResultSet rs=stat.executeQuery("select * from Table1 where user='"+user+"' and pass='"+pass+"'");
System.out.println("select * from Table1 where user='"+user+"' and pass='"+pass+"'");
int count=0;
while(rs.next())
{
{count=count+1;}
if(count==1)
{
JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"User Found,Access Granted");
ControlPanel cp1=new ControlPanel();
cp1.display();
}
else
{
JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"User not found");
}
}
}
```

Comment: So what's the actual problem? Do you just get the "User not found" message, or do you get an error of some kind?

Comment: Nothing is happening here and i didn't got any error. is my database connection correct ?

Comment: I don't see any obvious errors in your code. What, if anything, is in your `catch` block? Are you running this code under Java 8?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The JDBC-ODBC Bridge is obsolete and has been removed from Java 8, so `.getConnection("jdbc:odbc:...` is simply not going to work. For an alternative see

[Manipulating an Access database from Java without ODBC](https://stackoverflow.com/q/21955256/2144390)